# Allow PHP files in Orchard MVC site

Tags: php, wordpress, orchardcms, jetpack

I'm running Orchard on my main domain as CMS. On a subdomain, I have wordpress installed and now I wanted to install the Jetpack plugin. Per http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/your-website-needs-to-be-publicly-accessible-to-use-jetpack-site_inaccessible, you need to have xmlrpc.php available on your main domain, which would be the one where Orchard lives. I copied the file there, but get a 500 internal server error requesting it. I'm assuming this is because the ASP.NET MVC routing engine is picking up the request.

So the question is: what should I do to let IIS handle the xmlrpc.php file as a PHP file, and not as a part of the Orchard MVC site?

Answer (score 0):

Running two applications in the same IIS web application is not recommended, but if you must, read this post: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/280041

Comment: Ok. I will consult with the Jetpack people first to see if this is absolutely necessary. It's kind of idiotic when it is, but in that case I don't reallt have an option.